# datepicker in android does not show correctly

Tags: android, datepicker

I have the following code in xml layout for dataPicker :

```
                     <DatePicker
                    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For this my layout file is looking like this :

[image]

But in my device the dataPicker is looking like this :

[image]
Why the datePicker is looking like calender priview ?

Comment: Because maybe that's what the DatePicker looks like on the device you're running this code?!

Comment: I think there is not enough space to show the datepicker correctly

Comment: how can I solve this ?